# Get ID from checked row with Jquery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery datatables, it has checkboxes, a hidden column (Logged_ID).

Issue: When I filter the table and select a value it shows the value as if its the first page. e..g. In first page, If I select 3rd row then  Logged_ID 1704 will show up which is correct but if I Filter the table or select another page it still shows 1704 on selection of 3rd row.

> Jquery code snippet:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/BSA/BSAExceptionGrid",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    div.css("display", "none");

                    $('#BSAGrid').DataTable({
                        paging: true,
                        searching: true,
                        destroy: true,
                        "bInfo": true,
                        dom: '<lf<t>ip>',
                        data: response,
                        lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                        columns: [
                            { "data": "Logged_ID" },
                            { "data": "Logged_ID" },
                            { "data": "CustomerName" },
                            { "data": "PolicyNumber" },
                            { "data": "FirstDateToParticipant2" },
                            { "data": "LastDateToParticipant2" },
                            { "data": "ClientType" },
                            { "data": "TypeOfClient" }
                        ],
                        aoColumnDefs: [
                        {
                            aTargets: [0],    // Column number which needs to be modified
                            mRender: function (o, v) {   // o, v contains the object and value for the column
                                return '<input type="checkbox" id="chkBSA" name="chkBSA" class="cBSAChk"/>';
                            }
                        }
                        ,
                         {
                             aTargets: [1],
                             visible: false
                         }
                        ],
                        select: {
                            style: 'os',
                            selector: 'td:first-child'
                        }
                    });
                }


// Issue is coming here. // Get all checked row values
function MatchRecords() {
 var BSAvalues = new Array();
 var BSATable = $('#BSAGrid').DataTable();
            $('#BSAGrid').find('tr').each(function () {
                var row = $(this);
                if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
                    var v = BSATable.cells({ row: row.index(), column: 1 }).data()[0];  /// To get hidden Logged_ID value
                    BSAvalues.push(v);
                }
            });
}
```

> HTML code snippet:

```
<table id="BSAGrid" class="cBSAGrid display B1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Logged_ID</th>
                    <th>Client Name</th>
                    <th>Policy#</th>
                    <th>FirstDateToParticipant</th>
                    <th>LastDateToParticipant</th>
                    <th>Client Type</th>
                    <th>TypeOfClient</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>

         <input type="submit" disabled value="Match" onclick="MatchRecords();" id="btnMatch" style="-webkit-appearance: none;" />
```